# How to populate a dropdown list with Slamdata report

Tags: mongodb, slamdata

I'm using SlamData to create my report. I followed Slamdata's tutorial to populate a dropdownlist from database. I created a mark down with this query

> committer = {!`SELECT DISTINCT idCategory FROM "/demo/ReportDB/TMCMSReportData" ORDER BY idCategory}

It return this error:
[image]

Can you show me why I got this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query would be:

``` committer = {!`` SELECT DISTINCT idCategory FROM `/demo/ReportDB/TMCMSReportData` ORDER BY idCategory ``} ```

Note the use of back-ticks (not single quotes) to escape identifiers (the location in the file system) and the double back-ticks surrounding the Markdown snippet. These changes occurred recently when SlamData was [updated to use the latest version of Quasar](http://slamdata.com/news-and-blog/2016/02/19/slamdata-2-5-released-a-bold-new-step-into-the-world-of-post-relational-analytics/). It looks like not all documentation on the SlamData website has been updated yet.